# JQuery can't connect to Spring WebSocket

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-websocket

I'm trying to implement push notification using Spring and JS.

I've configured my service as follows:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {


  @MessageMapping("/hello")
  @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
  public Greeting greeting(String namethrows Exception {
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + name "!");
  }

}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
  }

}
```

On the client I'm trying to connect to the service:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8810/gs-guide-websocket');
```

But in the console I see the message:

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8810/gs-guide-websocket
```

If I try to hit the URL a get a greeting: `Welcome to SockJS!`

Why can't JS connect to the socket?

Comment: The call to `registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();` registers a STOMP over WebSocket endpoint with SockJS fallback. It seems that most of the code is from this [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/), which uses STOMP over websocket. Did you try the complete example?

Comment: We have restrictions on 3rd party code. I've got Spring but not stomp.js

Comment: If you'd like to use the WebSockets API directly, the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-server) could be of help. There are probably examples on the Internet, too. Just make sure they are not for STOMP.